# WP WPQuery, not running properly in WP CLI

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, wp-cli

I'm running a simple query just to find simple WooCommerce products, here is the query which works fine in the header of the site:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_type',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('simple')
        ),
    ),
);

$simpleProducts = new WP_Query($args);
```

This query returns 1065 products which are correct. If I run the same query through a WP CLI command, I get 0 posts... however, if I remove the tax query it's returns all the products on the site.

Here is the command that runs:

```
// Add the command.
if ( defined( 'WP_CLI' ) && WP_CLI ) {
   \WP_CLI::add_command('update-stock', \stockChecker::syncStockFile());
}
```

Has anyone had this issue with WP CLI?

**EDIT**

To add, this runs fine:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product_variation',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$products = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: I've created a custom WP-CLI command.

Comment: @leymannx I've added the CLI command above.

Comment: to simplify the issue, did you try it as a raw wp-cli eval-file PHP script to see what happens?

Comment: Out of interest, did you make any progress here?

Comment: Unfortunately, not @mozboz! Had to move it into the functions and call the WPCLI command from there... that seems to work.